# Better way to inner join tables where value in 1 table OR another table

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 3 tables and want to join them together. the query takes a long time. what's the best way to optimize the 2nd join?

t1 has id1, id2.
t2 has id1, id2.
t3 has only id1.

```
select t1.val, t2.val, t3.val from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1
inner join t3 
 on t3.id1 = t1.id2 or t3.id1 = t2.id2
where ...;
```

Comment: Sounds like you are using [tag:polymorphic-associations]? This is not a relational concept, and it's hard to use in SQL.

Comment: Approximately how many rows are there in those tables?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a match in exactly one of the tables, use `left join`:

```
select t1.val, t2.val, coalesce(t3_1.val, t3_2.val)
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id1 = t2.id1 left join
     t3 t3_1
     on t3_1.id1 = t1.id2 left join
     t3 t3_2
     on t3_2.id1 = t2.id2
where ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's split the conditions with table t3 in to two queries combined by union all (if you need unique value and there is chance to have duplicate records then use union instead of union all.

```
select t1.val, t2.val, t3.val from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1
inner join t3 
 on t3.id1 = t1.id2 or t3.id1 = t2.id2
where ...
union all
select t1.val, t2.val, t3.val from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1
inner join t3 
 on t3.id1 = t2.id2
where ...
```